# How these statements are defined by a single word?

Tags: definition

How to describe these statements in one word?

1. It takes values from a given set of values
2. It is an algebraic expression where the only operation is multiplication.
3. It is the algebraic sum of monomials.
4. It remains invariant irrespective of time and place.
5. It is the sum of exponents of all variables present in a monomials.
6. It is the degree of the highest monomials in a polynomial.

Comment: What is "it"? This is a very confusingly stated question.

Comment: Can we get a little more context for these? Is this for an abstract/modern algebra course? What sorts of answers are you hoping for?

Comment: Its in CBSE(India) syllabus of Maths of standard IX. I have edited the question and hope it is clear now.

Comment: Can you give one example which you know so that we can help with these.Thanks

Comment: I am not sure but the answer for the first statement is either "Probability" or "Function"

Comment: Just to clarify, each of the statements require a different word?

Comment: Right, that's what it asks.

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, it's not very clear what is being asked here. But here are my best guesses given the context:

1. is probably *function*
2. is probably *monomial*
3. is probably *polynomial*
4. is so vague that I can't attempt an answer.
5. is probably *degree*
6. confuses me. My best guess is *degree* but since that's used in the definition I would guess that is not what is being asked for. Maybe now that you know the definition for a monomial and a polynomial, you can remember the right word?

EDIT: In the comments, Hagen has some good alternate suggestions.

Comment: I would have guessed *product* for 2. But in light of the general topic it might be possible that 1. should in fact be *coeffcient*. And of course 4. chould then be *constant*.

Comment: Those make quite a bit of sense.